# Winsock Multi Clients on C#

Tags: c#, vb6, client-server, winsock, vb6-migration

I have a task to make a simple winsock chat program that use VB.6 as the client and C# as the server.
It works well when it is with one client. But I have trouble how it can handle multiple clients. Can any body help me please? I searched in google but I hardly found the answer.  Thx

Here is my code

When connection request come:

```
    private void sckMain_ConnectionRequest(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ConnectionRequestEvent e)
    {
        sckMain.Close();
        sckMain.Accept(e.requestID);
        IsConnect = true;

        //lstSocket = new List<clsSocket>();
        //runTCP();
        //sckMain.Close();
        //with this commands we accept the connection request to the server..
        //now we are connected with the client
        txtHistory.Text += "Client Connected :" + sckMain.RemoteHostIP + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

When receive data

```
    private void sckMain_DataArrival(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent e)
    { //ON DATA ARRIVAL
        string data = "";
        object objData = (object)data;
        sckMain.GetData(ref objData);
        data = objData.ToString();
        txtHistory.Text += "[" + sckMain.RemoteHostIP + "]: " + data + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

Comment: First, there are some managed network classes that you can use so that you don't have to use COM.  They are TcpListener and TcpClient.  When you have a listener, the Accept method returns a TcpClient.  You can then keep a List<TcpClient> of the clients.  Second, you'll want to implement a login protocol.  On initial connection maybe you'll have the client pass a user id so that you can share it with other users. Then they'd be able to send messages directly to one person instead of broadcasting the message to the group.

Comment: @Lorek : thx for the suggestion, I'm still learning C#. When I use TCPListener and TCPClient, can I still receive message from an application with VB6 winsock? Do you have any sample of TCPListener and TCPClient program?

Comment: I just googled it and found this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2418/Making-Socket-Based-Application-Using-TcpListener

Comment: If you want to send binary messages instead of just strings, here is a link to an article I wrote that can help you serialize/deserialize the messages in VB: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/808778/VB-BitConverter